# how to get the value of the selected spinner item out of the onItemSelected method

Tags: android, variables, spinner, local

I am trying to obtain the selected value from a spinner to store it and use it later. I have tried in two different ways:

1. return null value
2. print only the first value of the list, when I select another value it does not print anything.

way 1

```
public class genera_debate extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public String text;
 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genera_debate,container,false);
        list_of_interest =view.findViewById(R.id.subject_of_interest);
        String [] subject = {"Tema de interés","Política","Deporte","Animales","Videojuegos","Economía","Medicina","Cultura","Ciencia","Tecnología","Música","Otros"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject);
        list_of_interest.setAdapter(adapter);
        list_of_interest.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "value is"+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 return view;}
   @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         text=list_of_interest.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

way 2

```
public class genera_debate extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public String text;
   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genera_debate,container,false);
        list_of_interest =view.findViewById(R.id.subject_of_interest);
        String [] subject = {"Tema de interés","Política","Deporte","Animales","Videojuegos","Economía","Medicina","Cultura","Ciencia","Tecnología","Música","Otros"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subject);
        list_of_interest.setAdapter(adapter);
        list_of_interest.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        text=list_of_interest.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "value is"+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;}
}
```

I hope you can help me, regards

Comment: `subject` is an array of items, `onItemSelected` gives you a `position` for which item was selected, so why not just use `subject[position]` ?

Comment: @ a_local_nobody
yes i tried it but since i am doing it from outside the onitemselected method it only gets the position of the selected item once :(.any idea how to get the value each time i select a new option?

Comment: `since i am doing it from outside the onitemselected method` why are you doing it outside the method ?

Comment: because I need to pass that variable as an argument variable of a function along with other global variables at the same time

Comment: En todo caso ya solucione el problema

Answer (score 0):

Define your Toast inside the onItemSelectedListener method.

The problem here is that the Toast is being called when your view is being created as it is inside the onCreate method which is called once your activity starts hence your Toast is being called only when your view is being created that means only once.

If you want it to be appeared every time you select a new value you need to define it inside the onItemSelectedListener as this method will be called every time you select a new value in the drop down .

Hope this helps you.